# Hitting enter in tag selector to select tag posts the question

Tags: bug, status-norepro, tag-autocomplete

On Firefox 6, it seems that hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> to select the tag in the tag selector from the dropdown menu also posts the question. I don't believe this is intended behavior, and it is not observed in Chrome.

Here's a video of this happening (though it's not very enlightening since keypresses are not shown): http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1722364/out-3.ogv

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce this in Firefox. Hitting enter, when a tag is highlighted, simply enters the tag.